# Difference Between @SessionScope and @SessionAttribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, httpsession

I am using @SessionAttribute in my Web Project. And I'm also using the @SessionScope. However I have no clear picture in what scenarios that we need to implement them and what differences they have? Yours Answers will be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.boraji.com/spring-mvc-4-sessionattributes-example   or    http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-model-attribute-with-session/

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

`@SessionScope` gives hint to spring to create one instance of any `@Component` for a single session. When a bean with this type of scope (using this annotation) is referenced then within a single session this instance is used repeatedly.

`@SessionAttributes` is used basically for different purpose. Session attributes as indicated using this annotation correspond to a specific handler's model attributes, getting transparently stored in a conversational session. Those attributes will be removed once the handler indicates completion of its conversational session.